# CoffeeScript: How to return a array From class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, coffeescript

What is wrong in this class in CoffeeScript ??

```
@module "Euclidean2D", ->
  class @Point
    constructor: (x,y) -> 
      return if Float32Array? then Float32Array([ x, y ]) else Array(x,y)
```

I want it to behave like:

```
p = new Point(1.0,2.0);
p[0] == 1.0
p[1] == 2.0
```

But testing with Jasmine I get "Expected undefined to equal 1."

```
describe "Point", ->

    beforeEach ->
      @point = new Euclidean2D.Point(1.0,2.0)

    it "extracts values", ->
      (expect @point[0]).toEqual 1.0
      (expect @point[1]).toEqual 2.0
```

Is there an error in CoffeeScript or in Jasmine ??

Also all of it is in a module like:

```
@module = (names, fn) ->
  names = names.split '.' if typeof names is 'string'
  space = @[names.shift()] ||= {}
  space.module ||= @module
  if names.length
    space.module names, fn
  else
    fn.call space
```

In the Chrome Console I get:

```
a = new Euclidean2D.Point(1.0,2.0)
-> Point
a[0]
undefined
b = new Float32Array([1.0,2.0])
-> Float32Array
b[0]
1
```

**EDIT:** , again.. sorry

Has solved using an combination of @brandizzi and @arnaud576875 answers. The @module prposed in the official CoffeeScript Wiki did not work. The result is:

```
class @Point
        constructor: (x, y) ->
            return if Float32Array? then Float32Array([ x, y ]) else Array(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `new` to instantiate the object:

```
p = new Euclidean2D.Point(1.0,2.0)
```

If you want to return an Array from the constructor, do it explicitly:

```
constructor: (x,y) -> 
  return if Float32Array? then Float32Array([x,y]) else Array(x,y)
```

(By default, Coffeescript doesn't return values from the constructor, so you have to do it explicitly.)

---

You could have done that, too:

```
class @Point
  constructor: (x,y) ->
    @[0] = x
    @[1] = y
```

Comment: The new is there, sorry.. But I want to create an Float32Array and not just Array.. if there is not support for Float32Array then I use Array

Comment: then add a return before `if Float32Array? ...` in the constructor (coffeescript doesn't `return` values from the constructor, by default)

Comment: Ok, changed to that.. it still gives undefined.. Changed the question to reflect how it is now.

Comment: it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/neEp4/96/ ; try clearing your cache / re-compiling your scripts

Comment: Why did you use "class Euclidean2D" ?? In pratical, it is the same ?

Comment: yes, the result is the same; @module comes from your framework

Comment: Using class Euclidian2D instead of @module (came from github coffee Wiki) it doesn`t compile.. In firebug using the return method i get the error: "x is not defined" in the return Float32Array([x,y]).

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a constructor but expecting that it behaves like a function. The constructor, however, just sets values in the object to be returned. Since your constructor does not set any attributes in the initializing object, it really does not useful.

You have some alternatives:

1. Initialize the class as @amaud sugested.
2. Returns the value from the constructor as @amaud sugested (which does not make much sense to me. This is not the function of a constructor as I feel it. In this case the solution #3 seems better).
3. define a function instead of a class. IMHO, is the most simple and functional solution

   ```
   @Point = (x, y) ->
       if Float32Array? then Float32Array([x,y]) else Array(x,y)
   ```
4. If you want `Point` to be either a specialization of `Float32Array` or `Array`, use the option #1 but make `Point` to inherit from the class you want:

   ```
   superclass = if Float32Array? then Float32Array else Array  

   class @Point extends superclass
     constructor: (x,y) ->
       @[0] = x
       @[1] = y
   ```

**EDIT**: @amaud676875 posted an interesting question as a comment. Since a reasonable answer would involve some code, I am posting the answer as a edit.

@amaud, for verifying your point, I wrote the following CoffeeScript module:

```
class Float32Array extends Array
  first: -> # Just for testing
    @[0]


superclass = if Float32Array? then Float32Array else Array

class @Point extends superclass
  constructor: (x,y) ->
    @[0] = x
    @[1] = y
```

Then I imported the module in the console:

```
coffee> point = require './point'
{ Point: { [Function: Point] __super__: [ constructor: [Object], first: [Function] ] },
 Float32Array: { [Function: Float32Array] __super__: [] } }
```

and created a `Point`:

```
 coffee> p = new point.Point 3, 2
 [ 3, 2 ]
```

This `Point` has the `first()` method from `Float32Array`:

```
 coffee> p.first()
 3
```

and `instanceof` says it is an instance of `Float32Array`, too:

```
coffee> p instanceof point.Float32Array
true
```

So I bet `new Point x, y` returns an instance of `Float32Array`. Of course it is an instance of `Point`, too, and it is not a problem because `Point` *is-a* `Float32Array`, to use a classical OOP expression.

Comment: Are you sure `new Point(x,y)` really returns a Float32Array instance ? doesn't seem to

Comment: @amaud I responded as an edit in my post. See if it clarifies/make sense of the situation.

Comment: Thanks! Does it works with the native Float32Array too ? (c.f. `class Float32Array extends Array`). To me it seems that these typed arrays are a bit special, and I'm not sure you would inherit the benefits of those.

Comment: Solved using that.. thanks a lot, needed to remove the @module also, used the amaud class Euclidian2D to git some namespace

Comment: @arnaud to be honest, I have never seen this class before. I would love to test it with the native one. How could I access it?

Comment: .. just checked.. it does not have the benefits of Float32Array, I have to return in the constructor as @arnaud said.. Thanks you both!

Comment: @Canesin just for curiosity, what benefits of `Float32Array` the inheriting `Point` missed?

Comment: I see... I made some experiments here and saw what you are talking about. But it does not seem to be an issue with the inheritance itself; instead, it looks like a problem in the way we choose to set the values in the array. I made some tests with `Array` and, if we use `@push x` instead of `@[0] = x`, the length is there. (Since `Float32Array` has no `push()` method, I ran the tests with `Array`). I am curious about the reasons of it and posted a question about this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7450354/287976). You (and @ arnaud576875) may be interested in following it :)