# Why does setting positions in a subclass of Array not change its length? Should I not subclass array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

In the CoffeeScript program below, I create a subclass of `Array` which sets two positions in its constructor:

```
class SetPositionsArray extends Array
  constructor: (x,y) ->
    @[0] = x
    @[1] = y

  myLength: ->
    @length

sp_array = new SetPositionsArray 1, 2

console.log "sp_array: "
console.log sp_array
console.log "sp_array[0]: "
console.log sp_array[0]
console.log "sp_array[1]: "
console.log sp_array[1]
console.log "sp_array.length: "
console.log sp_array.length
console.log "sp_array.myLength(): "
console.log sp_array.myLength()
```

I would hope that this code would change the `length` property of `sp_array`, since it effectively sets positions on it. However, the output I get is:

```
$ coffee sp.coffee
sp_array: 
[ 1, 2 ]
sp_array[0]: 
1
sp_array[1]: 
2
sp_array.length: 
0
sp_array.myLength(): 
0
```

That is, the length is 0.

Then, I created another class which pushes values in the instance instead of setting them:

```
class PushValuesArray extends Array
  constructor: (x,y) ->
    @push x
    @push y

  myLength: ->
    @length


pv_array = new PushValuesArray 1, 2


console.log "pv_array: "
console.log pv_array
console.log "pv_array[0]: "
console.log pv_array[0]
console.log "pv_array[1]: "
console.log pv_array[1]
console.log "pv_array.length: "
console.log pv_array.length
console.log "pv_array.myLength(): "
console.log pv_array.myLength()
```

In this case, I get the expected result, except that there is an *actual* `length` attribute in the array (while I would imagine that it would be some internal detail):

```
$ coffee pv.coffee
pv_array: 
[ 1, 2, length: 2 ]
pv_array[0]: 
1
pv_array[1]: 
2
pv_array.length: 
2
pv_array.myLength(): 
2
```

So, why does setting the position in the array does not change its length?

*This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7421781/287976) for which I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421781/coffeescript-how-to-return-a-array-from-class/7422121#7422121).*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest explanation is: `length` is magic.

`length` obviously doesn't behave like an ordinary property, since it changes its value when you insert/delete other properties on its object (and, conversely, setting `length = 0` will delete other properties); but there's nothing special about the *identifier* "length". That means you can easily write `foo.length = 'bar'`, and the world will keep turning. Only on arrays does it have its special nature.

Now, you might expect when when you `extend` the `Array` constructor, that you get an array—but do you? Well, in one sense you do:

```
class PushValuesArray extends Array
(new PushValuesArray) instanceof Array  # true
```

Unfortunately, for the purpose of `length`, you don't. All the `extends` keyword does here is create a prototype chain, and the Array *prototype* has a distinctly non-magical `length` property:

```
Array::length  # 0
```

That's all you get on your `PushValuesArray` instance. Sadly, there's no way to duplicate that `length` magic on your own objects. Your only option is to either write a function instead (say, `size()`), or modify the `Array` prototype with the methods you want and use true arrays instead.

To sum up: **Subclassing `Array` won't get you very far.** That's why, for instance, jQuery has a very array-like API on its objects—

```
$('body').length  # 1
$('body')[0]      # [object HTMLBodyElement]
```

—but doesn't actually make those objects inherit from the Array prototype:

```
$('body') instanceof Array  # false
```

Answer (score 3):

Array.length is a special property that [doesn't work when subclassed](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/11/hooray/).

If you look at the compiled javascript for your first example the way CoffeeScript builds classes is by creating a function and calling `__extends(SetPositionsArray, Array);`. This method can't 'copy' the concept of length into your new class.

Answer (score 0):

The following Array subclass, using node.js and implemented in coffeescript, works by using util.inherits & Object.defineProperty

```
util = require 'util'

class NGArray extends []
  constructor : ->

  util.inherits @, Array

  Object.defineProperty NGArray.prototype, "length",
    get: ->
      i = 0 
      for k,v of @
        i++ unless isNaN parseInt(k) 
      i

array = new NGArray()
array[0] = 'value'
array[1] = true
array[2] = ->
array[3] = 568
array.push(false)
array.pop()

console.log(array.length) #4
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize  I'm rather late in the game here, but you shouldn't need to do what you're doing. Here's an example I've been tinkering with and I see no reason why it shouldn't work for you.

```
class ArrayWrapper
  constructor: (name, args...)
    @name = name
    @push.apply(@, args)
```

Once this is in place I can do this:

```
>>> relation = new Relation('foo',1,2,3,4,5)
Object[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> relation.length
5
```